# Why NSMutableDictionary don't want write to file?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutabledictionary, nsfilemanager

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathString]) 
    {
        infoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathString];
    } 
    else 
    {
        infoDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"BeginFrame",@"EndFrame", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], nil]];
        if ([infoDict writeToFile:pathString atomically:YES])
        {
            NSLog(@"Created");
        } 
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"Is not created");
            NSLog(@"Path %@",pathString);
        }
}
```

This is my code. I check if file is created, if not - I create a `NSMutableDictionary` and I write it to file at path, but  `writeToFile` method returns `NO`. Where is problem? If I create this file with `NSFileManager`  it works, but doesn't when I want to write a dictionary.

Comment: Where does `pathString` come from?

Comment: I said with [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:pathString contents:nil attributes:nil]; this file was create...

Comment: i have first metode init and there I alloc it

Comment: it seems like you made a mistake initalizing the `infoDict`. I mean objects should be keys and keys- objects.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`writeToFile:atomically` only works if the dictionary you call it on is a valid property list object ([see docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHDBHDB)).

For a `NSDictionary` to be a valid property list object, among other things, its [keys must be strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-SW2), but in your example the keys are `NSNumber` instances.

Comment: thx... this is problem... but it worked fine in 2011... without problems :D

Comment: Thanks! I just got tripped up by the requirement that all the keys have to be strings.

Answer (score 12):

You can not control the content you are going to write sometimes. For example, you can't avoid a `null` value when you are going to write a JSON object that is gotten from a server.

`NSData` is compatible with these "invalid" values, so converting `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` to `NSData` is an ideal way in these cases.

write:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:jsonObject];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

read:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: Awesome. As mentioned above you may not always be able to serialise JSON. This works great with my JSON.