# writeToFile not working with NSDictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, plist, nsdictionary

I looked around other similar questions about this but nothing really worked.

I managed to write only one pair (object / key) of the dictionary (e.g.: setObject:itemProperties[0] forKey[0]) on my Plist. But I would like all the objets and keys to be added. I didn't managed so far (return the error). Any help?

```
 // Path to Documents Folder

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"items.plist"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
    path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"items.plist"] ];
}

NSMutableDictionary *items;

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
    items = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
}
else
{
    // If the file doesn’t exist, create an empty dictionary
    items = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
}

// array of the item properties
NSArray *itemProperties = @[myItem.itemTitle, myItem.itemImage, myItem.itemPositionX, myItem.itemPositionY, myItem.itemHeight, myItem.itemWidth];

// Set the key values for each field    
NSArray *keys = @[@"Title", @"Image", @"PositionX", @"PositionY", @"Height", @"Width"];


[items setObject:itemProperties forKey:keys];

//Save dictionnary to Plist
[items writeToFile: path atomically:YES];

if (![items writeToFile:path atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"Error with creating Plist");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you properly use valid keys & values ?

> This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are
>   property list objects (instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber,
>   NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary) before writing out the file, and
>   returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects, since the
>   resultant file would not be a valid property list.

Reference : [writeToFile:atomically:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHDBHDB)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just checked my arrays and some objects are not in that list.

Answer (score 18):

You can not control the content you are going to write sometimes. For example, you can't avoid a `null` value when you are going to write a JSON object that is gotten from a server.

`NSData` is compatible with these "invalid" values, so converting `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` to `NSData` is an ideal way in these cases.

write:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:jsonObject];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

read:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: Instead of copy/pasting your answer from [Why NSMutableDictionary don't want write to file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713846/why-nsmutabledictionary-dont-want-write-to-file/20659846#20659846), you should flag this question as a duplicate of the one you originally answered (if it really is one). If it is not a duplicate, than your answer is invalid.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I can flag a question as a duplicate. I'll do it in the future.

Comment: Help me a lot, this works well!

Comment: that was our problem, that was the solution !