# Swift: Reading a plist from MainBundle and writing directly to Documents fails

Tags: swift, plist

Take the following file, named `Permissions.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
    <key>SomeKey</key>
    <false/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I'd like to read it in from my `MainBundle`, modify it, and write it out to my `.Documents`.  However, even if I leave it *unmodified*, the write fails.  The `Swift` syntax seems to have changed since [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498400/write-and-read-a-plist-in-swift-with-simple-data), and the other questions I could find were caused by [incorrect key types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652428/writetofile-not-working-with-nsdictionary), which would be odd given that I'm not modifying before writing out.  Here is the complete code to reproduce the error:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Read in the plist from the main bundle.
        guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Permissions", ofType: "plist") else {
            NSLog("Path could not be created.")
            return
        }

        guard NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path) else {
            NSLog("File does not exist.")
            return
        }

        guard let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) else {
            NSLog("Contents could not be read.")
            return
        }

        print(resultDictionary) // { Facebook = 0; }

        // Write it to the documents directory
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray

        guard let docsString = paths[0] as? String else {
            NSLog("Couldn't find documents directory; permissions could not be updated.")
            return
        }

        guard let docsURL = NSURL(string: docsString) else {
            NSLog("Couldn't convert the path to a URL; permissions could not be updated.")
            return
        }

        let plistURL = docsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Permissions.plist")
        let plistPath = plistURL.path!
        let plistString = "\(plistURL)"

        if !resultDictionary.writeToURL(plistURL, atomically: false) {
            NSLog("Writing file to disk via url was unsucessful.") // Failure
        }

        if !resultDictionary.writeToFile(plistPath, atomically: false) {
            NSLog("Writing file to disk via path was unsucessful.")
        }

        if !resultDictionary.writeToFile(plistString, atomically: false) {
            NSLog("Writing file to disk via path was unsucessful.")
        }

        print("URL: ",NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfURL: plistURL)) // nil
        print("Path: ",NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistPath)) // Prints
        print("String: ",NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistString)) // Prints

    }

}
```

**Edit**

I made a silly logic error in the original example (missing `!` in the last line) which was causing it look like it was failing when it wasn't.  However, the example now fails with the `URL` method but works with either the `path` or `String` interpolation methods.  Why is the `URL` method failing?

Comment: Why are you checking if the file exist at the bundle? if you know the file it is there it makes no sense. The file located in the bundle can't be deleted or changed.

Comment: Use the write-to-disk API returning an `NSError` to get more information.

Comment: You should create a single guard statement instead of five

Comment: @LeoDabus I was checking every step for the purpose of the example, to make clear that each was, in fact, passing.  I wouldn't write it like this in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
guard let docsURL = NSURL(string: docsString) else { ... }
```

To create an `NSURL` from a file path, use

```
let docsURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: docsString)
```

Conversely, you cannot use string interpolation to create a file path
from an `NSURL`:

```
let plistString = "\(plistURL)"
```

Use the `.path` method instead:

```
let plistPath = plistURL.path!
```

Or better, use the `writeToURL()` method to write your dictionary,
then you don't have to convert the URL to a path.

Comment: There was a stupid logic error in my example.  String interpolation and the `path` method work, but `writeToURL()` doesn't seem to.  I've updated the question.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall: `let docsURL = NSURL(string: docsString)` is also wrong, it should be `let docsURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: docsString)`.

Comment: Thanks very much, Martin--sorry for the trouble.